# Can I load two json files with different fields into one SQL table?

Tags: sql, json

I currently load these two different files into two different staging tables using two different sets of code and merge later. I'd like to get them both loaded into the same staging table. For File A the 'affiliations' and 'language' fields would be NULL and for File B 'specialties' and 'age' would be NULL. Can this be accomplished, or do the fields in the files need to match the fields in the table? From my experience if a column in the table is not present in the file, then it will fail to load.

[image]

JSON for File A

```
Declare @CustomerA varchar (max)
SELECT @CustomerA=BULKCOLUMN

FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '\\hlmofile.net\shared\IS\Automation\Cust\Data\', SINGLE_CLOB) json 
insert into [Customer].[CustomerA]
  SELECT 
 
 JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.name') as name,
 JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.address') as address,
 JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.city') as city,
 JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.state') as tate,
 JSON_QUERY(a.value, '$.specialties') as specialties, 
 JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.age') as age,
    
    FROM OPENJSON(@CustomerA ) as a
```

Json for File B

```
Declare @CustomerB varchar (max)
SELECT @CustomerB=BULKCOLUMN

FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '\\hlmofile.net\shared\IS\Automation\Cust\Data\', SINGLE_CLOB) json 
insert into [Customer].[CustomerB]
  SELECT 
 
 JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.name') as name,
 JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.address') as address,
 JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.city') as city,
 JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.state') as tate,
 JSON_QUERY(a.value, '$.affiliations') as affiliations, 
 JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.language') as language,
    
    FROM OPENJSON(@CustomerB ) as a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From my experience if a column in the table is not present in the file, then it will fail to load.

That's not correct. That only happens with `OPENROWSET (BULK` if you are retrieving a full table, not `SINGLE_CLOB` which is by definition includes the whole file.

And `OPENJSON` and `JSON_VALUE` only care if you add `strict` to the path. The other columns will just be `NULL`.

But you can simplify this somewhat, by using `OPENJSON` with a schema. And you can do it all in one step.

```sql
insert into Customer.CustomerB (
  name,
  address,
  city,
  state,
  affiliations,
  language,
  specialties,
  age
)
SELECT
  j.name,
  j.address,
  j.city,
  j.state,
  j.affiliations,
  j.language,
  j.specialties,
  j.age
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK N'FileNameHere', SINGLE_CLOB) f(Blob)
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(f.Blob)
  WITH (
    name nvarchar(100),
    address nvarchar(500),
    city nvarchar(100),
    state nvarchar(100),
    affiliations nvarchar(max) AS JSON,
    language varchar(50),
    specialties nvarchar(max) AS JSON,
    age int
  ) j;
```